# Kubernetes pod is not starting

Tags: docker, kubernetes

`kubectl run ls --image=tomcat --command -- pwd`

Using following command to start a pod.

Here is result of using `kubectl decribe pod`

Events:

```
FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath           Type        Reason    Message
---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------           --------    ------    -------
26s           26s             1       default-scheduler                               Normal      Scheduled Successfully assigned ls-2648590517-hvnrr to minikube
26s           26s             1       kubelet, minikube                               Normal      SuccessfulMountVolume       MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-3px95"
25s           20s             2       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{ls}     Normal      Pulling   pulling image "tomcat"
20s           15s             2       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{ls}     Normal      Pulled    Successfully pulled image "tomcat"
20s           15s             2       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{ls}     Normal      Created   Created container
20s           14s             2       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{ls}     Normal      Started   Started container
14s           12s             3       kubelet, minikube       spec.containers{ls}     Warning     BackOff   Back-off restarting failed container
14s           12s             3       kubelet, minikube                               Warning     FailedSync      Error syncing pod
```

If using `pwd` with `kubectl exec`, command works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pwd` command as you know is not a daemon, it just executes and exits immediately. By default, kubernetes tries to restart any pod that exits. In your case, the `pwd` command gets executed a few times, until kubernetes gives up because it failed too many times.

What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was doing a poc with kubernetes and trying to  learn why some of my commands were failing. Realized, Was missing a concept .

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [kubectl run](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run/) documentation with `--restart=Always` (the default) a `Deployment` is created which is expected to run in the foreground and not exit - a daemon as @whites11 said that gets restarted.  If you want the command to be run and then the container exit use `--restart=Never` which causes a `Job` to be created instead (see `--generator`) and that is expected in complete.